# When I change my reference level on my GLMER in R, why do the p-values change and why don't the estimates add up? Emmeans solution in answer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, p-value, categorical-encoding

I am new to this. My study has three conditions (between subjects - low coordination, high coordination, high coordination with ostensive cues) and three repetitions of a game (within subjects - Game 1, Game 2, Game 3). The outcome variable is binary (i.e., participant's left the game, they did not leave the game).

**I've carried out 3 GLMERs using the following code:**

```
S1_glmer <- glmer(left_game ~ condition + game + condition:game + (1 | participant),
                  data = S1_data,
                  family = binomial(link="logit"),control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
                  nAGQ = 1)
```

**See all three outputs below**

The condition estimates on the bottom two glmers add up, i.e, glmer 2, intercept for high coordination with ostensive cues is 9.1848 - minus -0.9203 for high coordination = 8.2645 which is the intercept for high coordination in glmer 3. But the condition estimates for glmer 1 do not add up to those for glmer 2 or glmer 3. According to the p-values in glmer 1, there is no significant condition difference between low coordination and the other conditions. But in glmer 2 and 3, there are significant condition differences. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

I changed the reference level to find out whether there was a significant difference between the 2nd and 3rd conditions: high coordination and high coordination with ostensive cues.

Now I feel like I can't trust the original results.

**Glmer 1) Output when reference level is low coordination, Game 1:**

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: left ~ cond + game + cond:game + (1 | participant)
Data: S1_data
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
176.7    209.8    -78.3    156.7      192 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7321 -0.0004  0.0001  0.0101  4.9872 

Random effects:
Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
participant (Intercept) 723.7    26.9    
Number of obs: 202, groups:  participant, 72

Fixed effects:
Estimate     Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 8.2474        1.9877     4.149  3.34e-05 ***
conditionHigh coordination 0.8632        2.2934     0.376   0.70664 
conditionHigh coordination with ostensive cues 1.8618        2.7681 0.673   0.50121 
gameGame 2                                     10.6282       2.3868     4.453   8.47e-06 ***
gameGame 3                                     14.3519       5.8753 2.443   0.01458 *
conditionHigh coordination:gameGame2           1.0957        3.4069 0.322   0.74774 
conditionHigh coordination with ostensive cues:gameGame 2  -8.5113 2.8270 -3.011  0.00261 **
conditionHigh coordination:gameGame 3         -2.8912       5.9182  -0.489    0.62518   
conditionHigh coordination with ostensive cues:gameGame 3 -10.1465 6.0885 -1.666  0.09561 .

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) cndHgc cHcwoc gamGm2 gamGm3 cHc:G2 ccwoc2 cHc:G3
cndHghcrdnt -0.621                                                 
cndHghcrwoc -0.494  0.421                                          
gameGame 2   0.252  0.035  0.050                                   
gameGame 3   0.304  0.002  0.024  0.583                            
cndHcrdn:G2  0.070 -0.100 -0.043 -0.446 -0.142                     
cndHcwoc:G2 -0.188 -0.032 -0.086 -0.819 -0.466  0.377              
cndHcrdn:G3 -0.159 -0.046 -0.028 -0.431 -0.837  0.280  0.348       
cndHcwoc:G3 -0.276 -0.004 -0.040 -0.545 -0.946  0.137  0.533  0.796
```

**Glmer 2) Output when reference level is high coordination with ostensive cues, Game 1:**

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: left ~ cond + game + cond:game + (1 | participant)
Data: S1_data
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
180.1    213.1    -80.0    160.1      192 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6992 -0.0009  0.0001  0.0153  4.6034 

Random effects:
Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
participant (Intercept) 425.6    20.63   
Number of obs: 202, groups:  participant, 72

Fixed effects:
                               Estimate     Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)       
(Intercept)                      9.1848         2.1924      4.189    2.80e-05   ***
condHigh coordination           -0.9203         2.3928      -0.385   0.700510
condLow coordination            -16.0097        3.6128          -4.431   9.36e-06   ***
gameGame 2                        1.9997        1.5684      1.275    0.202292       
gameGame 3                         4.0240       1.9118      2.105    0.035304   *
condHigh coordination:gameGame 2   8.4752       3.1819      2.664    0.007732   **
condLow coordination:gameGame 2   12.9762       3.5373      3.668    0.000244   ***
condHigh coordination:gameGame 3  6.1720        3.4743      1.776    0.075656   .
condLow coordination:gameGame 3   13.8269       5.5511      2.491    0.012745   *

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) cHcwoc cndLwc gamGm2 gamGm3 ccwoc2 cLc:G2 ccwoc3
cndHghcrwoc -0.483                                                 
cndLwcrdntn -0.738  0.251                                          
gameGame 2   0.231  0.060 -0.301                                   
gameGame 3   0.221  0.057 -0.287  0.498                            
cndHcwoc:G2 -0.178 -0.100  0.237 -0.870 -0.422                     
cndLcrdn:G2  0.158 -0.037 -0.436 -0.499 -0.113  0.456              
cndHcwoc:G3 -0.151 -0.084  0.203 -0.397 -0.835  0.475  0.111       
cndLcrdn:G3  0.249 -0.020 -0.457  0.042 -0.260 -0.020  0.485  0.252
```

**Glmer 3) Output when reference level is high coordination, Game 1:**

````
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
Approximation) [glmerMod]
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: left ~ cond + game + cond:game + (1 | participant)
Data: S1_data
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
180.1    213.1    -80.0    160.1      192 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6992 -0.0009  0.0001  0.0153  4.6034 

Random effects:
Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
participant (Intercept) 425.6    20.63   
Number of obs: 202, groups:  participant, 72

Fixed effects:
                                            Estimate    Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)        
(Intercept)                                     8.2645          1.7992           4.594  4.36e-06    ***                                                                                            
condHigh coordination with ostensive cues       0.9203          2.3926           0.385  0.700490
condLow coordination                           -15.0893         3.3701           -4.477 7.55e-06    ***
gameGame 2                                      10.1959         2.8428            3.685 0.000229    ***
gameGame 3                                      10.4749         3.0173            3.379 0.000727    ***
condHigh coordination with ostensive cues:gameGame 2  4.5010    3.1753          -2.669  0.007605    **
condLow coordination:gameGame 2                 -8.4752         3.5680           1.262  0.207126        
condHigh coordination with ostensive cues:gameGame 3  -6.1720   3.4707         -1.778  0.075355 .
condLow coordination:gameGame 3                  7.6549         5.2865           1.448  0.147617        

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) cHcwoc cndLwc gamGm2 gamGm3 ccwoc2 cLc:G2 ccwoc3
cndHghcrwoc -0.483                                                 
cndLwcrdntn -0.738  0.251                                          
gameGame 2   0.231  0.060 -0.301                                   
gameGame 3   0.221  0.057 -0.287  0.498                            
cndHcwoc:G2 -0.178 -0.100  0.237 -0.870 -0.422                     
cndLcrdn:G2  0.158 -0.037 -0.436 -0.499 -0.113  0.456              
cndHcwoc:G3 -0.151 -0.084  0.203 -0.397 -0.835  0.475  0.111       
cndLcrdn:G3  0.249 -0.020 -0.457  0.042 -0.260 -0.020  0.485  0.252
```
````

Comment: **tl;dr** whenever you have an interaction in your model, changing the zero point/reference level for some predictors will change the meaning, and hence the p-value, of the main effects of other predictors that are involved in the interaction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality

Comment: If a predictor X participates in interactions, you can't interpret the "main effect" of X meaningfully on its own. The reason is that we can't apply the recipe: "the interpretation of $\beta$ is the change in the outcome Y when we change X while keeping the other predictors fixed". We can't vary the main effect while keeping the interaction fixed. What comparisons do you want to make? It's worth learning how to use the [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) package.

Comment: Thanks, to editors, migrators and responders. @dipetkov thanks to you and Ben, I understand a bit more about the impact of the interactions now. Game is a bit of a nuisance variable, but I had to include it because of task fatigue over time. I was interested in the impact of the conditions on whether participants left the game. There were no sig diffs between the low coordination condition and the other conds for this outcome measure. However, for completeness, I was hoping to test whether there was a sig diff between the other two conds. How should I do this (instead of what I've done here)?

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks for your response.

Comment: You can get the three odds ratios with `pairs(emmeans(fit3, ~ condition | game, type = "response"))`. This calculates the odds ratios at each level of game. From the phrase "task fatigue over time" I suspect that the third game is the last game played. So it may be most relevant to focus on the final set of odds ratios. Then you'd use `pairs(emmeans(fit3, ~ condition | game, at = list(game = "3"), type = "response"))`.

Comment: The odds ratios estimates are parametrization independent: you'll get the same answer with any of the three fitted model which are actually the same model, with parameters coded differently but equivalently.

Comment: Someone (possibly the OP) should write these comments up as an answer and post them (unless someone can find an appropriate duplicate Q&A; one might exist)

Comment: @BenBolker, ok, thanks, I will do

Comment: @dipetkov, thanks, I will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**These comments address why the p-values change and the estimates don't add up:**

1. whenever you have an interaction in your model, changing the zero point/reference level for some predictors will change the meaning, and hence the p-value, of the main effects of other predictors that are involved in the interaction. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality
   – Ben Bolker
   2 days ago
2. If a predictor X participates in interactions, you can't interpret the "main effect" of X meaningfully on its own. The reason is that we can't apply the recipe: "the interpretation of β is the change in the outcome Y when we change X while keeping the other predictors fixed". We can't vary the main effect while keeping the interaction fixed.
   – dipetkov
   2 days ago

**These comments address how to compare all three conditions to each other** (NB. within each condition, there are 3 games in chronological order - there may be task fatigue over time):

It's worth learning how to use the emmeans package:
[emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html)
[interactions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html)

You can get the three odds ratios with pairs(emmeans(fit3, ~ condition | game, type = "response")). This calculates the odds ratios at each level of game.

From the phrase "task fatigue over time" I suspect that the third game is the last game played. So it may be most relevant to focus on the final set of odds ratios. Then you'd use pairs(emmeans(fit3, ~ condition | game, at = list(game = "3"), type = "response")).

The odds ratios estimates are parametrization independent: you'll get the same answer with any of the three fitted model which are actually the same model, with parameters coded differently but equivalently.
– dipetkov
21 hours ago

These videos helped me understand emmeans:
[intro](https://youtu.be/_okuMw4JFfU?si=zmEp-F23rDNa3ahs)
[interactions](https://youtu.be/cqmMNR6x73g?si=ChVHlgT6p_S6NWzs)

This blog was also helpful:
[getting started with emmeans](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/03/getting-started-with-emmeans/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for posting; to be more specific, my idea was that rather than cutting and pasting comments, you would compose a complete answer *based* on the comments ...

Comment: @BenBolker, apologies, I'm new here, I'll write something more coherent at the weekend, once I've sorted the gmmeans.

Comment: Good start at writing an answer. Here is also the Interaction [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html) in the emmeans documentation. (And I apologize for writing comments rather than an answer; that turned out to not be very helpful.)

Comment: @dipetkov, thank you, all your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @dipetkov, I have created these gmmeans: EM means based on estimate: `EMM = emmeans(S1_glmer1, specs = pairwise ~ game | condition) EMM$contrasts %>% summary(infer=TRUE)` EM means based on odds.ratio:
`emmeans(S1_glmer1, specs = pairwise ~ game | condition, type = "response") EMM$contrasts %>% summary(infer=TRUE)` I am confused about whether I need to adjust for bias because of my random effect of participant?

Comment: These code snippets are about comparing games for each condition. Why are you looking into those comparisons?

Comment: @dipetkov, I wanted to further explore the significant interaction and the significant effects of game

Comment: This is perhaps better achieved with a plot that visualizes all the relevant information. In your case there are three conditions and three consecutive games, so the nine probabilities Pr(left_game | condition, game) can be nicely summarized in a graphics. PS: This sounds like it may be a new question? It's best to keep each CV thread on one specific topic.

Comment: @dipetkov, yes, you are right, I've jumped to a different question. I agree about the graph, thanks.